# White Screen After Facebook Share Using Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure why this code gives me a white screen(mobile devices) without response or null(laptop/desktop) with response after I have shared successfully my post on facebook. The post seem to go through to facebook and I believe I have loaded everything I needed. It might be a permissions issue, but I find that less likely now that it has occurred on both my android and ios devices. I also don't know if it is a issue with my facebook settings in the developer account. Either way if anyone knows what could be causing the issue or any ideas on how to solve it, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
$('#fb-custom-button').on('touchstart click' , function(){

    var url = window.location.href;
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: url,
        caption: 'An example caption',
    }, function(response){
        alert(response);
        if (response === null) {
        } else {
        }

        $('#mask, .window').hide();

    });



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that there was a mobile way of sharing.

```
shareurl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=" + APP_ID + "&display=popup&href="+ URL + "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URI; 
location.href = shareurl
```

I also realized that facebook cannot handle get parameters when using this so I have to make a redirector for that.